# Is there a standard or recommended external subtitle format for Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, video, media-player, subtitle

I need to load subtitles as external xml/text (representing different language) files for a video. However, I'm trying to decide on a schema/format for my external file, and have come across two options:

- SAMI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971327.aspx
- Timed Text: http://www.w3.org/AudioVideo/TT/

Right now I'm leaning towards SAMI since it seems like Timed Text is relatively new and still being drafted. Also, Netflix mentioned that they were working on an implementation for it: http://blog.netflix.com/2009_06_01_archive.html
Does anyone have any suggestions/recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with SMIL and another priority format that goes with this [Silverlight player](http://sl2videoplayer.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.  SAMI is interesting too...  I have seen more general support for SMIL, but for what it sounds like you are doing I would say that either SAMI or SMIL would be good since there is no built in support for any format (today) in Silverlight.

You are going to have to process it and render it yourself so I would just pick the simplest format.  Unless you are expecting to be getting these from external sources in which case you should first look at what that format is.

I am in the broadcast industry and most of the CC files that I get are SMIL based files.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a project using SAMI subtitles - it works just fine. 
Write me in case you need some sample code to get startet.